# rewrite rule, two domains pointing to same directory, redirect one file at one domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How to possible redirect a single file having two domains pointing to the same directory.

I have:

```
domain.com
domain2.com
```

going to `/var/www`

if I hit domain2.com I go to `/var/www/index.php`

I'd like to have a rewrite rule that states `domain2.com/index.php` should go to `domain2.com/thefile.php`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in `/var/www`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /thefile.php [L]
```

If you want to redirect the browser, you'll need to add a `R` to the rule's flags: `[L,R]`